# Efficiently search a long list of lists

Tags: python, performance, search, data-structures

I have a long list of hexahedral point coordinates, for example:

```
[[0,    57,  2948,    56,   449, 14953, 15002,  5446],
[  449, 14953, 15002,  5446,   450, 14954, 15003,  5495],
[  450, 14954, 15003,  5495,   451, 14955, 15004,  5544],
[  451, 14955, 15004,  5544,   452, 14956, 15005,  5593],
[  452, 14956, 15005,  5593,   453, 14957, 15006,  5642],
....]
```

Each row defines a hexahedron cell, and by iterating over each cell, I extract the defining faces of the cell (6 faces), and add each face to a list `processed_faces`

[image]

All of this is fine, but because some cells are sharing the same face, I needed a way to check if the current face has been processed before or not (also needed later for connectivity calculations, so no way out of this).

```
 for cell_id, cell in enumerate(cells):
        faces = get_faces(cell)
        for face in faces:
            # have we met `face` before?
            if not self.face_exists(face):
                self.add_face(face)

            # link the face to the cell who shares it
            self.link_face_to_cell(face, cell_id)
```

The bottleneck of my code is `face_exists()`, for which I tried two different approaches:

1. Sort each processed face, convert it to a tuple (to be hashable), add the tuple to a list of tuples, and simple check if a face exists by `tuple(sorted(face)) in faces`. But this is AWFULLY SLOW.
2. Implement a trie data structure, which works just fine (and about 100x faster than method 1), but I am not satisfied with the performance

   ```
   class TrieNode:
       __slots__ = ['index', 'is_end', 'children']
       def __init__(self, index: int):
           self.index = index
           self.is_end = False
           self.children = {}


   class Trie:
       __slots__ = ['root']
       def __init__(self):
           self.root = TrieNode(-1)

       def insert(self, face: List[int]):
           node = self.root

           for point in face:
               if point in node.children:
                   node = node.children[point]
               else:
                   new_node = TrieNode(point)
                   node.children[point] = new_node
                   node = new_node

           node.is_end = True


       def search(self, face: List[int]) -> bool:
           node =self.root

           for point in face:
               if point in node.children:
                   node = node.children[point]
                   continue
               else:
                   return False

           if node.is_end:
               return True

           return False
   ```

Sorry for the long question, in summary I am looking for two things:

1. An alternative data structure for mesh storage, that allows my fast search needs. OR:
2. If trie is suitable for my application, is there a python library (hopefully with a C backend) that allows storing list of numbers, because libraries I came across are mostly designed for strings.

Comment: How about using a `set` for storing faces?

Comment: @alex Hi alex, I tried `frozenset`  as a hashable face and a`set` of faces, and the performance is great. About 4x faster than trie. If you write an answer I will accept it. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible drop-in solutions would be to use a `set`/`frozenset` for storing faces. Sets have great lookup performance and are simple to use here.